# Is the differential of a surjection a surjection?

Tags: differential-geometry, tangent-bundle

Let $\phi:M \to N$ be a smooth map. Let $\text d\phi:TM\to TN$ denote its differential. If $\phi$ is surjective then is $\text d\phi$ surjective?

I don't know much about differential geometry. I don't have a counterexample, and it seems like a plausible statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define $\phi\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ by $\phi(x)=x^3$, then $\phi$ is a smooth surjective map. However, $\mathrm d\phi$ is not surjective at $0$, since it is the null function.

Comment: Ha! Thanks. Should've seen that.

Comment: This seems like a sufficient condition though: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem

Comment: Indeed, if $\phi$ has a local inverse near $a$, then $\mathrm d\phi_a$ is surjective.